# OutOfMemoryError crash Android

Tags: android, multithreading, crash

Help me fix this app crash. Thanks.

Log here:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:  
  at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate (Native Method) 
  at java.lang.Thread.start (Thread.java:1063) 
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:920) 
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1327) 
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.v.run (Unknown Source) 
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.u.a (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:20) 
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.future.ac.b (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:18) 
  at com.google.android.gms.ads.safebrowsing.e.a (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:15) 
  at lr.handleMessage (:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesA:10) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:145) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6892) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.ru (ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: You're out of memory.  Usually this means either you're using way too much, or you have a leak.  But there's no easy answer to this, you need to take heap dumps and figure out where your leak is.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in Menifest.xml in Application tag;

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Comment: this won't solve the problem only postpones the crash by few more moments that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Your question have very vast solution.
Best way to figure out the real problem is to have look at

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory.html

Also you can take heap dumps to find where is a memory leak. Form your logs i only tell you that you are using lower specification device.